# Using void return type and take in an array of integers as a parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, integer, return, void

I was given an assignment for class in which they want us to make an array of 10 and have a menu with several prompts such as changing numbers of the array, getting the sum of the array, etc. They want each menu option to have its own method with variations of:

```
public void enterNum(int[] args)
```

I am having issues understanding how to store an array between the 5 methods when they are required to be set to void as well as I am not sure how to format when sending the info to the method. I have built a draft as a switch statement

```
using System;

namespace Lab
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int input, x, y, sum = 0;
            int[] initArray = new int[10];
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Would you like to: \n1) Enter a number\n2)Print the array \n3)find the sum of the array\n4)Reset the array\n5)Quit\n");
                input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (input)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Write("Enter the slot: ");
                        x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Enter the new value: ");
                        y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        initArray[x] = y;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(" | " + initArray[a]);
                        }
                        Console.Write("\n");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
                        {
                            sum += initArray[b];
                        }
                        sum /= 10;
                        Console.WriteLine(sum);
                        sum = 0;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
                        {
                            initArray[c] = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                }
            } while (input != 5);
        }
    }
}
```

an example of where I'm having issues is with

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
int[] NewArr = new int[10];
enterNum(NewArr);
//trying to change number of array
printSum(NewArr);
//getting sum from array established in Main
}

public void enterNum(int[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the slot: ");
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the new value: ");
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            NewArr[x] = y;
            return;
        }
public void printSum(int[] args)
        {
           for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
                        {
                            sum += NewArr[b];
                        }
                        sum /= 10;
                        Console.WriteLine(sum);
                        return;
        }
```

Comment: Did this code work for you? What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: An array is a reference type. It won't be copied when you pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] NewArr = new int[10];
            enterNum(ref NewArr);
            //trying to change number of array
            printSum(NewArr);
            //getting sum from array established in Main
        }

        public static void enterNum(ref int[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the slot: ");
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the new value: ");
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            args[x] = y;
            return;
        }
        public static void printSum(int[] args)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
            {
                sum += args[b];
            }
            sum /= 10;
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Also the line:

```
sum /= 10;
```

is going to calculate the average, not the sum.